# Difference, in relation to minus sign, between the processes: $gg \to q\bar q$ and $qg\to qg$

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, quantum-chromodynamics

I have been computing some QCD cross-sections lately and I have followed the instructions given by Peskin and Schroeder. However I stumble upon this situation: Where the minus sign in $qg \to qg$ comes from? Because the crossing symmetry involved is pretty clear, but that minus sign results to me confusing...

I attach the differential cross-sections from Peskin and Schroeder

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gluons are vector bosons, but quarks are fermion. By crossing symmetry, you flip an anti-quark in s-channel $gg\to q\bar{q}$ to quark t-channel $qg\to qg$. By fermion statistics, you must change the sign. So there is a "-" sign in the result.